# como saber si un switch esta on/off en android Switch Preference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Quiero saber si el switch esta activado o destactivado al momento de hacer "click" en el. tengo lo siguiente:

```
enable_social_recommendations = (Preference) findPreference("enable_social_recommendations");
                    enable_social_recommendations.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                // aqui que deberia hacer para comprobar si al momento de hacer click esta ono activado el switch???

                return true;


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando tu código, estas usando la clase [Preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html) y por medio de `onPreferenceClick()`, no puedes obtener un estado simplemente obtienes la preferencia y su valor.

> [onPreferenceClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener.html) Se llama cuando se ha hecho clic en una
>   preferencia.

En cambio si usaras [SwitchPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html) por medio de [onPreferenceChange()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) puedes determinar cuando se realiza un cambio en la preferencia.

```
SwitchPreference estado = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("estado");
estado.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if(!((Boolean) newValue)) {
                Log.i("Preferencias", "NO ACTIVADO.");
            } else {
                Log.i("Preferencias", "ACTIVADO.");
            }
            return true;
    }
});
```

Esto es un ejemplo de como sería declarado el `SwitchPreference` dentro del layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Mis Preferencias" >
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="estado"
            android:title="verifica el valor del estado" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar un cambio en el Switch podrías detectar el cambio dentro de `onPreferenceChange()`, en el caso del ejemplo que pongo te indicará si esta activado o desactivado el `Switch`.