# Como guardar estado de botón tipo Switch en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en AndroidStudio y tengo una activity que contiene un Switch (on/off) que pide el permido de acceder a los contactos.

Lo que sucede es que al momento de hacer que el switch pase a estado "on" me pide el permiso respectivo, el cual queda seleccionado y la proxima vez que inicio la app ya sabe que se lo concedí, pero no así el switch, el cual aparece nuevamente en estado "off". (debería seguir estando en "on" por que ya le dí el permiso).

.java

```
//accion swith contactos
    switch_contactos.setChecked(false);
    switch_contactos.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){

            if(isChecked){

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Vincula_cuentas.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

            }


        }
    });
```

xml

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
    android:id="@+id/switch_contactos"
    />
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!

Comment: intentaste guardar algún dato en preferencias? o utilizar una preferenceActivity?

Comment: Como sugerencia, mas que mostrar el switch te recomiendo implementar el workflow completo para pedir permiso en tiempo de ejecución dado que contempla mas opciones como ser si el usuario no quiere que le vuelvan a pedir permiso.

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de inicializar el Activity verifica si el permiso ha sido asignado con
[`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, stringPermission)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) que retorna 
[`PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#PERMISSION_GRANTED) si el permiso fue asignado o de lo contrario [`PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#PERMISSION_DENIED).

Por ejemplo:

```
int estadoPermiso = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Vincula_cuentas.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
boolean permisoAsignado = estadoPermiso == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
switch_contactos.setChecked(permisoAsignado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deseas es algo similar a esto:

[como saber si un switch esta on/off en android Switch Preference?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48509/como-saber-si-un-switch-esta-on-off-en-android-switch-preference/48587#48587)

pero en este caso no tienes SwitchPreference, por lo tanto puedes usar una preferencia para guardar/obtener el valor del estado del switch:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void saveValuePreference(Context context, boolean valor) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("estado_switch", valor);
    editor.commit();
}



public boolean getValuePreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getBoolean("estado_switch", false);
}
```

para usarla de esta forma:

```
 //obtiene valor.
boolean estado_switch = getValuePreference(getApplicationContext());

  switch_contactos.setChecked(estado_switch);


    switch_contactos.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
            //guarda valor.
            saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), isChecked);

            if(isChecked){

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Vincula_cuentas.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

            }


        }
    });
```